# Поиск по текстовым файлам в Windows на C++

Tags: windows, c++builder, c++

Программа для поиска текстовых файлов, в которых встречается искомая строка текста, C++ Builder.

Проблема вот в чем, необходимо подключить поиск по всему компьютеру, только в текстовых файлах, необходимо выбирать в каком каталоге искать. Что-то на подобии обычного поисковика винды. Ну и, конечно, хотелось бы услышать более рациональный способ организации поиска.

Answer (score 2):

Можно применить простой алгоритм. Есть строка str (это открытый файл) и подстрока sub.

Начинаем поиск sub[0] в str[i], как только нашли, ищем sub[1] в str[i] и т.д., пока не найдёт весь sub.

P.S. Скорее всего этот ответ наберёт отрицательные балы)) Но такой алгоритм реализовать нужно обязательно! Вначале делается он, в потом изучается более сложный, реализуется и тестируется с простым на правильность поиска и на скорость!

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен поиск подстроки в файлах, то ищи здесь: [Поиск подстроки в строке](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Если нужен полнотекстовый поиск, то наверное придётся строить обратный индекс. Есть проект[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html). А [CLucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/) - уже на C++. Можешь интегрировать в свою программу, чтобы строить индекс и быстрый поиск.

Comment: Мне такое не подходит, у меня вся программа состоит из поиска. Мне нужна самописная программа

Comment: тогда неясно, в чём вопрос. "проблема в том, что.." - плохое описание проблемы, поскольку проблемы никакой нет или она нетривиальна и известна только Вам

Comment: проблема возникла в выборе рационального решения метода поиска, более быстрого и более надежного.
необходимо это написать на C++ Builde
хотелось бы организовать такой же поиск как в Total Commander но как он организован, увы не знаю. Вот и ищу ответ.

Comment: Возьмите исходник grep из любого \*nix и подправьте для плюсов.

Answer (score 0):

Самый рациональный поиск подстроки в строке - [Алгоритм Кнута-Морриса-Пратта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0).